# Linq OrderBy to group objects with the same sets

Tags: c#, linq

I have a set of objects that themselves contain a set.

```
private class Pilot
{
    public string Name;
    public HashSet<string> Skills;
}
```

Here's some test data:

```
public void TestSetComparison()
{
    var pilots = new[] 
    {
        new Pilot { Name = "Smith", Skills = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "B-52", "F-14" }) },
        new Pilot { Name = "Higgins", Skills = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "Concorde", "F-14" }) },
        new Pilot { Name = "Jones", Skills = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "F-14", "B-52" }) },
        new Pilot { Name = "Wilson", Skills = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "F-14", "Concorde" }) },
        new Pilot { Name = "Celko", Skills = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "Piper Cub" }) },
    };
```

I want to use `OrderBy` in Linq so that:

- Smith and Jones are ordered together because they fly the same planes
- Higgins and Wilson are ordered together because they fly the same planes
- doesn't matter whether Higgins+Wilson end up before or after Smith+Jones
- preferably Smith is before Jones (stable sort) but this isn't too important

I think I need to implement an `IComparer<Pilot>` to pass into `OrderBy` but don't know how to handle the "doesn't matter" aspect (above) and the stable sort.

**UPDATE:**

I want the output to be an *array* of the *same five* `Pilot` objects but in a *different order*.

Comment: What you're describing is a **GroupBy**, not an **OrderBy**. Instead of "ordered together", you should see it as "grouped".  But it's a bit of an unusual one since you're trying to group on a list of options rather than a specific property (still looking into that before I post an answer). **Question:** What if there was an extra pilot with B-52 and Concorde? Is he left in a group by himself since no one hqs the **exact** same skills?

Comment: You don't need an `IComparer<Pilot>`, but an `IEqualityComparer<HashSet<string>>` that checks if two `Skills` sets are equal. Than use this comparer in a `GroupBy` call to group by `Skills`. Afaik, `GroupBy` keeps the order of elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `GroupBy` you have to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` for the type you are going to group (`HashSet<string>` in your case), e.g.

```
private sealed class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<HashSet<string>> {
  public bool Equals(HashSet<string> x, HashSet<string> y) {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;
    else if (null == x || null == y)
      return false;

    return x.SetEquals(y);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(HashSet<string> obj) {
    return obj == null ? -1 : obj.Count;
  }
}
```

And then use it:

```
 IEnumerable<Pilot> result = pilots
    .GroupBy(pilot => pilot.Skills, new MyComparer())
    .Select(chunk => string.Join(", ", chunk
       .Select(item => item.Name)
       .OrderBy(name => name))); // drop OrderBy if you want stable Smith, Jones

 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
 Jones, Smith
 Higgins, Wilson
 Celko
```

**Edit:** If you want an *array reodered* then add `SelectMany()` in order to *flatten* the groupings and the final `ToArray()`:

```
 var result = pilots
    .GroupBy(pilot => pilot.Skills, new MyComparer())
    .SelectMany(chunk => chunk)
    .ToArray();

 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result.Select(p => p.Name)));
```

Outcome:

```
 Jones, Smith,
 Higgins, Wilson,
 Celko
```

Note that string.join combines the names of each group in one line, i.e. `Jones, Smith` both have the same skill set.

Run it as **[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gcAGG6)**

Comment: @onedaywhen: I see; if you want the array just add `SelectMany` to *flatten* the `GroupBy` and the final `ToArray`; please, see my edit

Comment: outcome must be the array of pilots but sorted as per spec, that's why I think I want a IComparer to use in OrderBy.

Comment: ...yes, I see it now! I think you missed the fact one can use `x.SetEquals(y)` in the `Equals` implementation. How would this change  `GetHashCode` implementation?

Comment: @petemoloy: thank you! `x.SetEquals(y);` is a better implementation than my emulation; there's no need to change `GetHashCode`: if sets are equal they have the same hashcode (number of items)

Comment: Any reason not to make the comparer class generic? there's nothing specific to `string` in the implementation.

Comment: @petemoloy: well, `private sealed class MyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<HashSet<T>>` is quite OK in the context; I didn't declare it as a generic since I thought you're solving a very *specific problem*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following implementation of **HashSetByItemsComparer** to accomplish what you need:

```
public class HashSetByItemsComparer<TItem> : IComparer<HashSet<TItem>>
{
    private readonly IComparer<TItem> _itemComparer;

    public HashSetByItemsComparer(IComparer<TItem> itemComparer)
    {
        _itemComparer = itemComparer;
    }

    public int Compare(HashSet<TItem> x, HashSet<TItem> y)
    {
        foreach (var orderedItemPair in Enumerable.Zip(
            x.OrderBy(item => item, _itemComparer),
            y.OrderBy(item => item, _itemComparer), 
            (a, b) => (a, b))) //C# 7 syntax used - Tuples
        {
            var itemCompareResult = _itemComparer.Compare(orderedItemPair.a, orderedItemPair.b);
            if (itemCompareResult != 0)
            {
                return itemCompareResult;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

It is not the most efficient solution probably, since it orders hashsets for each comparison separately. You may need to optimize it if using with millions of pilots and many skills, but for small numbers it will work just fine.

Usage example:

```
var sortedPilots = pilots.OrderBy(p => p.Skills, new HashSetByItemsComparer<string>(StringComparer.Ordinal));

foreach (var pilot in sortedPilots)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pilot.Name);
}
```

And output is:

```
Smith
Jones
Higgins
Wilson
Celko
```

So **it preserves equal items ordering** (default behavior of `OrderBy` - you don't need to worry about it). By the way, solution with `GroupBy` would not allow you to restore items order as far as I know.

Comment: I was using `HashSet` objects so that I could simply use `SetEquals` - can it be used here?

Comment: I'm afraid SetEquals will check just for equality, but you need to order items in OrderBy...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample with orderby

```
  var groups = from c in GridImage (Your List)
               orderby c.grouping (Your Item inside List)
               group c by c.grouping;
```